# Regular Expressions nth match

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I realise that this may seem like a stupid request but I'm going to ask anyway.

I wish to use a regular expression to find every nth comma in a list of numbers ie:

```
    88574,93243,129659,135504,136357,141052,141619,141619,142195,144622,144946,...
```

could then have every 4th comma ',' replaced by ',\r\n' thereby turning a list of numbers into a grid of 4 by n rows.

finding all commas was simple :

```
    [^0-9]
```

which from the above list will find all commas. How can I now group these matches to exclude three in every four.

I could do this with PHP preg_matches but I am using this with a mysql regular expression replacement function so would prefer a pure regex answer (if one exists).

The Function that I'm using in MySQL is below:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `regex_replace`$$  

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1`   
    FUNCTION `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original TEXT)   
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) CHARSET latin1  
        DETERMINISTIC  
    BEGIN  
     DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000);  
     DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1);  
     DECLARE i INT;  
     SET i = 1;  
     SET temp = '';  
     IF original REGEXP pattern THEN  
     loop_label: LOOP  
       IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN  
                 LEAVE loop_label;  
       END IF;  
       SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);  
         IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN  
            SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);  
       ELSE  
          SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);  
                END IF;  
       SET i=i+1;  
              END LOOP;  
     END IF;  
     RETURN temp;  
    END$$
```

as you can see the regex it's self does not have to handle complex matching. Therefore a regular expression which is capable of selecting the nth comma would be sufficient.

I hope this clarifies the problem.

Fin

EDIT:

I have added the lib_mysqludf_preg library to the serve which contains the preg_replace function. This is a PCRE implementation for MySQL and should work if I can answer the problem of the regex for selecting every-fourth ',' and replace with ',\r\n'.

Comment: This might be a good start for grouping into sets of four numbers: ([0-9]*[^0-9]){4}

Comment: Thanks James,
Very similar answer to Tims below. Please see the response to him and the updated question.

Thanks Again,
Fin

Comment: I don't do MySQL, but if I'm reading your edit right, you now have access to `preg_replace`, so @Tim's solution should be viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:[^,]*,){4}/', '\0\r\n', $subject);
```

This matches four comma-delimited values in a row (I'm assuming that you won't have commas inside of strings within a group) and adds a CRLF after them.

[EDIT]
The above is a PHP based solution

For a pure MySQL solution, install lib_mysqludf_preg and use:

```
    SELECT preg_replace('/(?:[^,]*,){4}/', '${0}\r\n', `fieldname`) as 'new_layout' from `tablename`;
```

Many Thanks to all that contributed.

Comment: Thanks for your anser Tim, It's very close to what I want to do, but not quite there. What your regex does is to match the entire group of chars ie '88574,93243,129659,135504,' whereas I need to just match every 4th comma ie:  

88574,93243,129659,135504,136357,141052,141619,141619,142195,144622,144946,177824,...
    no    no     no     yes     no     no    no     yes     no     no     no    yes

I can't use PHP as the result is being processed by a MySQL function.

I hope this comes across clearly

Comment: MySQL regexes are not up to this task. They can only select columns that match or don't match a regex. That's it.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the use of MySQL and added the function I'm using.

Comment: I still don't see a way - to only select the comma, you'd need lookaround assertions, and MySQL doesn't support those. You'll have to step through the string character by character, count the commas and act on every fourth one.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I must have been having some kind of brain-fart. Once I got lib_mysqludf_preg properly compiled and installed the following gives me exactly what I needed from within MySQL:  SELECT preg_replace('/(?:[^,]*,){4}/', '${0}\r\n', '88574,93243,129659,135504,136357,141052,141619,141619,142195,144622,144946,177824,... [MORE NUMBERS HERE] ...212489,217352);  You were so increadably close at the outset (notice the '${0}' is the only difference) I simply have to give you credit for the right answer. Cheers, Fin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match every comma, then the more straight-forward pattern `,` will work as well.

For matching every fourth comma, if MySQL supports look-behind, perhaps you could you could use `(?<=(^|\r\n)(\d+,){3}\d+),`. That assumes that each replacement is performed before the next match is made, however. Otherwise perhaps `(?<=^((\d+,){4})*(\d+,){3}\d+),` would work.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support lookbehind assertions. Not to mention indefinite repetition inside lookbehind. Your regex would work fine in .NET, though.

Comment: Thanks! Kind of suspected that. Was worth a try though.

Comment: Thanks Henko,

One last thing it would only select the fourth instance of a comma not every fourth (one-in-four). I have updated the question one last time.

Comment: Given that your regex engine supports look-behind, I believe the patterns would match *every* fourth comma. Which one of the patterns to use depends, as I mentioned, on whether they are matched/replaced one at a time or all at once.

Comment: Thanks Henko,
My bad. I've found what I think is my point of confusion, although the PCRE lib does support lookbehind it doesn't support variable repition inside lookbehind. Is there any way that (?<=^((\d+,){4})*(\d+,){3}\d+), can be re-written for this eventuality. Thanks again, Fin